# (Batch) How can I detect if windows is using a dark theme or a white theme?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I wanted to learn how to detect whether the system's theme is white or dark.

---

Basically the idea of my code is:
`if "%windowstheme%"=="white" ( color f0 ) else ( color 0f )`.

I want to make it so matches the window's color.

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the fact that this will be OS specific/limited.

Directly in [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd):

```sh
For /F "EOL=H Tokens=3" %G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize" /V "SystemUsesLightTheme" 2^>NUL') Do @If %G Equ 0 (Color 0F) Else Color F0
```

Or from a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```sh
@For /F "EOL=H Tokens=3" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query
 "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize"
 /V "SystemUsesLightTheme" 2^>NUL'
) Do @If %%G Equ 0 (Color 0F) Else Color F0
```